# InstallShield and ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, installshield

I want to confuse my source code using ConfuserEx so I created a ConfuserEx-project file which looks like this:

```
<project baseDir="." outputDir="." xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
    <rule pattern="true" inherit="false">
        <protection id="rename" />
        <protection id="ctrl flow" />
        <protection id="ref proxy" />
        <protection id="anti debug" />
        <protection id="anti dump" />
        <protection id="constants" />
        <protection id="resources" />
        <protection id="anti tamper" />
      </rule>
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\MainApplication.exe" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Component.Hardware.dll" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Component.Log.dll" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Component.Service.dll" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Component.Software.dll" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\AsynchronousSocket.dll" />
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Instrumentation.dll" />  
</project>
```

Since I want to deploy my application through a setup I created an InstallShield Setup of my MainApplication-Project. I choose primary output.

In my Postbuild-Event in Visual Studio I call the Confuser.CLI.exe with the crproj-file as parameter. However, only the `MainApplication.exe` and the `AsynchronousSocket.dll + Instrumentation.dll` have been modified with ConfuserEx. The 4 Component.*.dll files aren't.
I have to say that all assemblies are different projects. So my project solution structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
    MyProject.MainApplication
    MyProject.Component.Hardware
    MyProject.Component.Software
    MyProject.Component.Log
    MyProject.Component.Service
    MyProject.AsynchronousSocket
    MyProject.Instrumentation
    MyProject.Setup
    MyProject.sln
    MyProject.crpoj
```

My guess is that I take the wrong assemblies used by InstallShield. I also tried to take the assemblies in `MyProject.Component.Service\bin\Release` and `MyProject.Component.Service\obj\Release` but neither of these options worked. 
I don't think that using `MainApplication\obj\Release` works because there is only the `MainApplication.exe` located.

Can anyone please tell me from where InstallShield takes the primary output or if I am missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is multiple crproj files, one for each binary, and specify the project specific crproj file in the post build step in EACH project. 
MainApplication.crproj

```
<project baseDir="." outputDir="." xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
    <rule pattern="true" inherit="false">
        <protection id="rename" />
        <protection id="ctrl flow" />
        <protection id="ref proxy" />
        <protection id="anti debug" />
        <protection id="anti dump" />
        <protection id="constants" />
        <protection id="resources" />
        <protection id="anti tamper" />
      </rule>
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\MainApplication.exe" />
</project>
```

Component.Hardware.dll.crproj

```
<project baseDir="." outputDir="." xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
    <rule pattern="true" inherit="false">
        <protection id="rename" />
        <protection id="ctrl flow" />
        <protection id="ref proxy" />
        <protection id="anti debug" />
        <protection id="anti dump" />
        <protection id="constants" />
        <protection id="resources" />
        <protection id="anti tamper" />
      </rule>
     <module path="MainApplication\bin\Release\Component.Hardware.dll" />
</project>
```